# Missing dependencies when running wildfly on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, wildfly

I have a problem with deploying project on Wildfly 8.0.0 from eclipse.

When I try to run project from eclipse through Run on Server on project I get following information in [project-name].war.failed file

```
\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"games-platform.war\\\".component.FCulture1DGameEngineImpl.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.gamesSD]\"
```

with many other missing dependencies (103 lines of missing dependencies like that)

On eclipse console i see information about missing dependencies like thie

```
service jboss.naming.context.java.module.games-platform.games-platform.ManagePlayersService-climate (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."games-platform.war".component.ManagePlayersService-climate.JndiBindingsService]
```

Also many of them (and from different projects so it does not seem like one missing library or class but more like configuration issue though I may be wrong).

On the Wildfly management page I cannot see any project on manage deployment tab.

When I try to run Wildfly through console using standalone.bat the application starts fine and I'm able to access it through http. Also it is visible on Wildfly management page.

Solution contains few projects. One of them (platform project) is connected to server in eclipse and others are running using it. They are attached on the platform project pom.xml as a dependency.

I tried to look for a problem but none of solutions I tried to apply worked.
I was checking whether my datasource from persistance.xml

```
<jta-data-source>java:/gamesSD</jta-data-source>
```

match datasource on standalone.xml

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/gamesSD" pool-name="gamesSD" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
<security-domain name="gamesSD" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="gamesSD"/>
```

I also check if jar files, that I added, have module.xml files and are matching in names.

This project is inherited so I don't have much knowledge about its configuration as well as I'm not Wildfly expert. Therefore if you need some more information about configuration of Wildfly or project let me know and I will add it here.

I'll be grateful for any help as I don't have any more ideas how can I make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Right after posting that question I looked back once more to standalone.xml and notice that one of properties jndi-name did not have java:/ prefix. After adding it I was able to start project from eclipse.

Don't know why was it starting from console previously though. If anyone knows answer to this I would be glad to mark it as answer.